# Integration of oscillatory function does not converge in python

Tags: python, scipy

I want to evaluate the integral of a function using scipy.integrate.quad. Here is how the integrand looks like:
[image: Integrand of oscillatory function]
We can notice that most of the contribution from that integrand will come from .1 to 4 or 5 ish. For x = 10 and more, while the function is oscillatory (hard to tell on the picture), it is very small and keeps getting smaller.

Here is what the result of the integration from 0 to some upper bound looks like. The upper bound of the integration is on the x axis.
[image: Integration of integrand up to some upper bound]
Here, while the result seems to be stable for the first hundred x's, it is no longer the case after, even if I was expecting a straight line...

I am quite new to python, and I don't know what is the best course of action. My best guess for now would be to take some value smaller than 100 as an upper bound for my integral, and discard the other values because it is just a bad convergence from integrate.quad.

**Edit:**
To plot the second graph, I used the scipy.integrate.quad function. However, if I just take the points that I generated to plot the integrand (first figure) and use this in [scipy.integrate.simps](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) and vary the maximum x up to which I integrate, I get consistent results.

Comment: Without any source code or original data it's incredibly hard for anybody to see what's going wrong here

Comment: I can certainly add some code. Could you tell me what would be helpful? The function that I am integrating is quite complicated, so I am not sure that showing the whole code would be helpful.

Comment: Are your `y` values between 0 and 8e-11? that will lead to precision problems using float32 and could even using float 64. The weird behaviour could be due to it, just a thought though

Comment: @gionni yes, there are... That could be the reason, then.

Comment: Try and create a minimum example that demonstrates your problem (which is a good idea for debugging anyway). Something like the relevant function you're using to integrate and its input. Without seeing it for ourselves we can only guess.

Comment: What is weird in addition to the comment by @gionni, is that in the first figure that wiggle at x=200 corresponds to y < 1e-11 while in the "zoomed" version (Fig.2), the flat line corresponds to y=3.5e-11. It seems that you are not plotting the same data.

Comment: @AGNGazer the second plot is the integration result for different upper bounds, i think

Comment: @AGNGazer As gionni is saying, the second plot is indeed the result of the integration for different upper bounds.

Comment: Well, when I use scipy.integrate.simps, with different values for x_max, I get consistent results... That's a start.

Comment: I would also guess the problem is due to precision issues. Have you tired renormalizing your function before integration?

Comment: @gionni Having the function range up to 8e-11 is not any worse than having it up to 8. In floating point arithmetics, `8e-11 + 5e-11` is as easy and robust as `8e-1 + 5e-1`.

Comment: @Alex good point, I guess if all the inputs are in the same range yes, it doesn't really matter. It was just a quick guess :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the integrand has an important feature that is much smaller than the range of integration, it may get "overlooked" by the adaptive `quad` routine. In constrast, `simps` does not miss them if you use fine enough mesh, but may take longer to evaluate. I'll describe two ways to deal with this, the second being more practical.

#### points parameter

You can use the `points` parameter of `quad` to make sure this does not happen. Here is an example, where I integrate Gaussian function `exp(-x**2)` on the interval [-1000, 5000]. This function is localized near 0; pretty much all of it is in the interval [-5,5] so I include `points=[-5, 5]` to make sure this range is not overlooked. (The points are required to be within the range of integration, hence the appearance of `if`).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x: np.exp(-x**2) 
numpoints = 1000
t = np.linspace(-1000, 5000, numpoints)
y = np.zeros((numpoints,))

for i in range(numpoints):
    y[i] = quad(f, -1000, t[i])[0]      # integration without points
plt.plot(t, y, 'r') 

for i in range(numpoints):            # using points if upper bound is above 5 
    y[i] = quad(f, -1000, t[i], points=[-5,5])[0] if t[i] > 5 else quad(f, -1000, t[i])[0]
plt.plot(t, y, 'b') 
plt.show()
```

The red curve is the output without `points`, the blue one is with `points`. The latter behaves as it should: rises from 0 to pi/2 and stays there.

[image: results]

#### Reusing previous calculation

A much more efficient approach to calculating antiderivative at multiple points is to use the previously computed value, adding to it the contribution of the  interval that was not integrated over.

```
y = np.zeros((numpoints,))
for i in range(1, numpoints):
    y[i] = y[i-1] + quad(f, t[i-1], t[i])[0]
plt.plot(t, y, 'g')
```

This has the same output as the blue curve above.

Comment: Thanks, I would not have thought to use "points" to pass the range over which the function has its significant contributions. I thought it was only for tricky points, such as singularities or discontinuities. Interesting.